# How to remove old html and append new one using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, frontend

I am appending elements using HTML template strings when a click event is triggered. As shown below.

```
for (var j = 0; j < className.length; j++) {
    className[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
        //techniques.deleteChild(); 
        jquery(techniques).empty();
        tmpObj[this.id].forEach((idTechs) => {
                htmlSelect += `<option class="idtechs">${idTechs}</option>`;
            })
            //techniques.appendChild(htmlSelect);
        techniques.innerHTML = htmlSelect;

    });
}
```

When I click on another button the old content to be removed and append new one. But this adds content to existing content.
I tried

```
innerHTML = '',
remove()
```

But no use.

Comment: `techniques.innerHTML = '';` will work fine, unless it is a jQuery object, in which case you would use `empty()` on it

Comment: They've already mentioned that `.empty()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There's not enough context. What is `techniques`, is it a string, jquey object, etc...?

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce your issue preferably in the form of a snippet. Also provide errors that you get.

Comment: Can’t add more detailed answer without further information about your code, but for me the problem lies in your `forEach` loop. `techniques.innerHTML = content`, if techniques is a DOM object (and not jquery object), should replace all the old HTML inside. So you see your old content not because it isn’t deleted, but because it is added again when you build your `htmlselect` string

Comment: If `techniques.innerHTML = htmlSelect`, works, then the empty should as well.  However `jquery(techniques).empty();` <= is incorrect due to the invalid case on `jQuery`.  And if that is all this is, this is a typo question.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov The first statement says the append works, so `techniques.innerHTML = htmlSelect` works, according to the OP.  So it is an Element

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Good catch.

Comment: techniques is an object.